# When printing a notebook in Mathematica 10, code sections do not wrap

Tags: notebooks, printing

I have a Mathematica 10 notebook where I am using code sections.  The text in the code section does not wrap when printing.  Is there a setting that I should use to allow the code to wrap?

Comment: the default style setting for `Code` is `PageWidth->Infinity`. You will need to change this locally for each cell or via a style sheet edit.

Comment: Mike - Thank you most kindly!

Comment: Go to Format >Word Wrapping to do this for each cell or Format>Edit Stylesheet to do it for your notebook. If you need help with the stylesheet edit do some searches to question on here ...you will find a lot of answers.

Comment: Hi Mike - I will need to dig into this a little more.  Format> Wordwrap seems to truncate text in Code cells instead of wrapping.  There are probably other properties that also need to be set.

Comment: The `Code` cell style does not wrap. For wrapped code, use the `Input` style.

Comment: Hi m_goldberg - was wondering about that.